# For what values of p does $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

**$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}dx$
How do I analize for what values of $p$ there is convergence without integrating?**

**My try:**
I split it in  $\int_0^1 \frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}dx +\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}dx$

For the second one $ \frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}\sim \frac{2x^p}{x^3}= \frac{2}{x^{3-p}}  $  because $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}}{\frac{2x^p}{x^3}}$ is a constant It is a well known result that $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^a}dx  $  converges for $a >1$, then $3-p>1 $, so $p<2$

**what about the first one?**  I can't use the same $"\sim"$, since know I have $x \to 0$ Mathematica says it does converge, how do I prove it? It is  a well-known result that $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^a}dx  $  converges for $a <1$, but I don't know how to reduce the integrand to an equivalent function of the form $1/x^a$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: HInt: for small $x$, $x+1\sim1$.

Comment: @J.G. so the integrand is $\sim$ to $2x^p/1^3=2x^p=2/x^{-p}$ so it converges for $-p<1 \iff p>-1$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one we can consider two cases

- $p\ge 0$ the integral converges
- $p<0$ by $q=-p>0$ we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2x^p}{(x+1)^3}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{2}{x^q(x+1)^3}dx$$

and as $x \to 0$ we have $x^q(x+1)^3 \sim x^q$ indeed

$$\frac{\frac{2}{x^q(x+1)^3}}{\frac{1}{x^q}}=\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}\to 2$$

therefore the integral converge for $q<1$ that is $-p<1 \iff p>-1$, as you correcly noted in the comments.

Formally, we are referring to the [limit comparison test for integrals](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eehallman/spring-2015/compTest-proof.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at $x=0$, we have $p > -1$, and looking at $x = \infty$, we have $p < 2$.

Thus, $-1 < p < 2$